# I always get an error when typing commands in psql but not if I copy past the command

Tags: postgresql, terminal, copy, paste, psql

Every time I type a command in psql it throws an error, but if I copy and paste the exact same command it works. For example, I typed this:

```
# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db_name TO user;
```

and got:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GRANT"
LINE 2: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db_name TO user;
        ^
```

Then I did a copy/paste on a new line with:

```
# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db_name TO user;
```

and it worked:

```
GRANT
```

The above is copied exactly from terminal changing only the db_name and user.

This happens every time I try to type in a command. Using 10.8.2 and PostgresApp from Heroku.

Any ideas?

Comment: all of the slash commands seem to work find though. e.g. \l, \d, etc.

Comment: The "LINE 2" would suggest a missing `;` to terminate the previous command, no?

Comment: Aw maybe that's it, I do tend to forget the `;` a lot. Perhaps I've just been doing that on the previous command every time I've tried to run this as I've only just started using psql.

Comment: I can reproduce that error message with something like `select * from t<return>grant;` where `<return>` is a newline. Keep an eye on the prompt it will change from `=>` or `=#` to `->` or `-#` when `psql` is waiting for you to terminate a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mu is too short answered this in the comments. I was indeed just forgetting to add the semicolon then retyping the command. It seemed that this was happening every time because I had only been using psql for about an hour.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the same error occurred but with having a semicolon at the end, I had to quote the params like:

```
sudo -u root psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE \"my_database\" TO \"my_database_user\";"
```

I also could verify this via pgAdmin/Database Properties/Security Tab/